# Fields been made non editable for a custom profile using Field level security, but user can still edit the field

Tags: profile, field-level-security, custom-profile

We are using multiple profiles and needs to make few fields in Opportunity as view only - non editable field. We have made the required changed in field level security of the profile, and also done necessary modification through Object manager. The "Edit Read Only Fields" is already deselected.

Comment: If you deselect the View & read-only check boxes then the field is not visible to the respective profile. If you want to make it read-only then you we should select both the checkboxes

Comment: Have you checked if any permission sets are assigned to that user which provides them edit access to the resp. fields?